# Is association in mathematica ordered or not?

Tags: associations

Does the association `<|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>` in Mathematica have order or not? If I iterate the association multiple times, is it guaranteed that the items will be iterated in the same order?

Comment: I have not used association much, but for me, it makes little sense to talk about "order" of keys. The point is that one gives a key, and gets the value associated with that key by a lookup. Like  a hash table. If you depend on an "order" of keys in the lookup table to do something, then I think you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Nasser: It's not the most frequent use case, but sometimes you want to aggregate data in an Association, then later process the key/value pairs in the order they were discovered. And I often find it handy that `BarChart`, `ListPlot`&friends don't jumble association data I pass them. So I'm glad Wolfram made them ordered.

Comment: @nikie Thanks for clarification :)